# How to mock a method call using Mockito

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I have the following problem using Mockito for unit testing:

I have this method:

```
@Override
public void handle(HttpExchange httpRequest) throws IOException {
    Object[] outputResult = processRequest(httpRequest);
    String response = (String) outputResult[0];
    Integer responseCode = (Integer) outputResult[1];
    httpRequest.sendResponseHeaders(responseCode, response.length());
    OutputStream os = httpRequest.getResponseBody();
    os.write(response.getBytes());
    os.close();
}
```

And I want only to test this method, not the `processRequestMethod` that is called internally (that I would like to test separately in anthoer test), so I need to mock it and to check at the end of the test that the methods write and close of the `OutputStream` class have been called.

I have tried two ways, but no luck with none of them:

```
@Test
public void handleTest() throws IOException {
    RequestHandler requestHandler=mock(RequestHandler.class);
    String response = "Bad request";
    int responseCode = HttpURLConnection.HTTP_BAD_REQUEST;
    Object[] result={response,responseCode};
    when(requestHandler.processRequest(anyObject())).thenReturn(result);
    when (httpExchange.getResponseBody()).thenReturn(outputStream);
    requestHandler.handle(httpExchange);
    Mockito.verify(outputStream,times(1)).write(anyByte());
    Mockito.verify(outputStream,times(1)).close();
}
```

With the code above, the `processRequest` method is not called, but neither is the handle method that I want to test, so the test is failing in the line:

```
Mockito.verify(outputStream,times(1)).write(anyByte());
```

Saying that this method was not called at all.

However if I add the parameter `CALL_REAL_METHODS` when creating the mock, like this:

```
@Test
public void handleTest() throws IOException {
    RequestHandler requestHandler=mock(RequestHandler.class,CALLS_REAL_METHODS);
    String response = "Bad request";
    int responseCode = HttpURLConnection.HTTP_BAD_REQUEST;
    Object[] result={response,responseCode};
    when(requestHandler.processRequest(anyObject())).thenReturn(result);
    when (httpExchange.getResponseBody()).thenReturn(outputStream);
    requestHandler.handle(httpExchange);
    Mockito.verify(outputStream,times(1)).write(anyByte());
    Mockito.verify(outputStream,times(1)).close();
}
```

Then the `processRequest` method that I want to skip is actually called when the method executes this line:

```
when(requestHandler.processRequest(anyObject())).thenReturn(result);
```

Any clues of what can be wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in your test instead of

> ```
> RequestHandler requestHandler=mock(RequestHandler.class,CALLS_REAL_METHODS);
> ```

use `Mockito.spy()`:

```
      RequestHandler requestHandler=spy(RequestHandler.class);
      doReturn(result).when(requestHandler).processRequest(httpRequest);
```

you may want the `doReturn().when()` form rather than the `when().thenReturn()` because the first does *not* execute the method whereas the latter does.

---

On the other hand I'd prefer to move `processRequest()` to another class where you can inject an instance of into  `RequestHandler` which would make mocking more straight...

Comment: Didn't know about spy. It worked like a charm. Thanks!